# Compile external library inside an R package

Tags: python, r, r-package, cran

I am building an R package with algorithms for ordinal and monotonic data classification, and I have a method called `svmop` that uses a version of a external library called `libsvm-weights` that is implemented in C but has a python wrapper.

I am using that library thought python using `reticulate` package, this way:

```
...
svmopredict<-function(models,test){
mysvm<-import_from_path("svmutil",system.file("python","python",package ="pkgName"))
pred<-mysvm$svm_predict(...)
...
```

where `svmutil` is placed in `package/inst/python/python`. However, that actually requires a built shared library to work. Actually I have the shared library built for linux and placed under `package/inst/python` , but as far as I know any form of binaries are unacceptable to CRAN.

So is there any way to  indicate the package to compile that library for windows or linux depending on the machine it is being installed? or is there any other better way to to this while being CRAN acceptable?

Comment: I would take my cue from other packages on CRAN that depend heavily on external libraries, e.g. `rgdal`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html "The 'GDAL' and 'PROJ.4' libraries are external to the package, and, when installing the package from source, must be correctly installed first."

Comment: Is your package source available at, e.g., a GitHub repo?

Comment: sure! https://github.com/CristinaHG/OCAPIS